# Elimination of hiss over entire recorded track

Tags: audio-recording, noise, music

I am new to recording, I've started trying to record some of my guitar/vocals. I recently brought a mic but my budget was limited, so it was only around 40£. Whenever I record with it there is a distracting hiss over anything i record, are there any ways I can eliminate this?

So far I have tried a basic noise gate, but when I am recording sound the hiss is still present over the guitar/vocals when I am creating enough sound to go over the noise gate. (Here is a [sample recording](https://homerecording.com/bbs/data/audio/78/78489-9a42e358d7e3384c972706fb276c47c3.mp3) showing the problem.)

I am recording using a subzero dynamic mic with an XLR to USB connector straight into my MacBook running GarageBand.

Cheers all.

Comment: I guess those cables have no preamp gain control, so the manufacturer has to account for the loudest signal a mic could put out.  That means the gain is going to be too low for a quiet vocalist singing into a low-output dynamic mic.  Sure you can do EQ and noise reduction and all of that, but it’s not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well in post-process, you could easily noise-cancel the hiss sound. But that can be done after the fact. If you want to remove the hiss sound you're hearing while recording, I'm not sure what can be done.

In Adobe Audition, open the recorded file and find a spot where there's hiss; mark it and then Right-click and choose "**Capture Noise Print**". You then go to Effects - Noise Reduction / Restoration - Noise Reduction.

Then, you can change the values to your needs. I hope this can be helpful!